# Selenium starts up a Chrome session but crashes right after

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I receive one of these errors when attempting to open up a session.

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
>   from chrome not reachable
>     (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
>   from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
>     (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

ChromeDriver = 80.0.3987.106

I googled these errors and none of the solutions helped, here's my current code: (one of the solutions suggested adding Chrome options)

```py
from selenium import webdriver

class YoutubeBot():
    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

EDIT: I have now found out that this issue is fixed by using headless, I'd still like to test my code while writing it, is there another solution perhaps? (I'm using the Xfce4 DE on Arch Linux)

Comment: Are you running this on a computer with no desktop? You might need to run Chrome in headless mode.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have a desktop environment, the Chrome window pops up for a second or two but displays nothing of use, then just crashes with one of the errors.

Comment: @GregBurghardt update: looks like it doesn't crash in headless mode though, that's strange.

Comment: That is definitely strange.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Chrome Browser* session.

---

You need to consider a couple of things:

- The absolute location of the *ChromeDriver* must be passed through a *Key* / *Value* pair as follows:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/qa/Documents/Python/chromedriver')
  ```
- While initializing the session you need to use the **`options`** argument instead of `chrome_options`.
- So effectively, you code block will be:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  class YoutubeBot():
      def __init__(self):
          chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
          chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
  ```

Comment: I have the default path, so it shouldn't matter either way, nevertheless, I tried your solution and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple, `sudo` the file. 
I feel stupid and should've checked this earlier, probably should've taken this into consideration.
When running, all I had to do was `sudo python -i main.py` and Chrome magically booted up without an error.

Comment: Does your user have read and execute permissions for Chrome and ChromeDriver? Usually `sudo` is like hitting a thumb tack with a sledgehammer. I would worry about running Chrome and ChromeDriver as `root`... unless I was a hacker. Then I would thoroughly enjoy it. :-)

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have read, write, execute permissions on both Chrome and ChromeDriver. Perhaps I don't have these permissions on the Selenium package or Python?